# Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10 somehow blocking access to websites

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I get the following error message when I open Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10.

> This page is accessing information that is not under its control. 
>   This posses and security risk. Do you want to continue?

I click “Yes,” it will open the homepage. After that, it won’t go anywhere else. If I try to go to Google, the browser goes white, the home page address doesn’t change, and this message pops up again.  If I click “Yes” again, nothing happens. The address bar remains the home page, and the tab shows blank.

Can anyone help? [Microsoft Edge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/getstarted-get-to-know-microsoft-edge) is a pain, I don’t want to use it.  It works, but its slow, the pop up blocker in not effective.

Both Edge and Firefox work fine, I don't use chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust security level at internet option.

Click setting at Internet Explorer, internet option, choose security tab.